# Упростить выражение.

Tags: python

Есть два списка, находим данные.

Дано:

```
v = [465,641,638,637,644,645,648,689,709,1022,1032,1065,1067]
g = [(705L,), (637L,), (638L,),]
```

Получаю:

```
res = [x for x in g if x[0] in v]
print res
[(637L,), (638L,)]
```

Обход последовательности, интересует варианты как можно блок кода упростить

```
x = []
for j1 in res:
   #тут передаем данные в MySQL
   res2 = dbHandle.execute(sql.format(j1[0],'mul_add)).fetchall()
   if res2:
       x.append(res2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможен вариант двух генераторов, что сделает меньшим, конечно, только кол-во строк.

Само выражение становится сложнее:

`x = [dbHandle.execute(sql.format(j1[0], mul_add)).fetchall() for j1 in res]
x = [i for i in x if i]`